# Rewrite query in lucene

Tags: search, lucene, url-rewriting

When lucene want to compute weight of query it first call *searcher.rewrite(Query)*,what does this function do for each types of query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query rewriter turns higher-level query clauses into lower-level clauses that perform better. The end result is functionally identical.

For example, the javadoc for `Query.rewrite` says:

> Expert: called to re-write queries into primitive queries. For example, a PrefixQuery will be rewritten into a BooleanQuery that consists of TermQuerys.

If Lucene is to perform an accurate query cost analysis, it needs to rewrite the query into its fastest form.